# How to get lowest value from posts with the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

My sample table:

```
ID | Post_id | Score
1  | 1       | 33
2  | 1       | 43
3  | 1       | 27
4  | 1       | 66
```

I want to get rows with the lowest value (Score). In this case it is:

```
ID | Post_id | Score
3  | 1       | 27
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_id = '1' GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY Score ASC
```

But that doesn't work because it returns me: Score: 33

How to fix it? What if I have thousands of rows and want post_id to be unique for the lowest values?

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two (or more ) rows with the same, lowest value?

Comment: Get only first row

Comment: What version of MySQl are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use subquery selecting min values for each `post_id`.

```
SELECT a.* FROM records a
JOIN 
( SELECT post_id, MIN(score) as min_score
  FROM records  GROUP BY post_id
) b
ON a.score=b.min_score;
```

Output

```
| id  | post_id | score |
| --- | ------- | ----- |
| 3   | 1       | 27    |
| 5   | 2       | 20    |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/otpDKVpXN1QxhEtSgJCEHt/0)

Answer (score 2):

For a single `id`, just remove the `group by` and use `limit`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE post_id = 1
ORDER BY Score ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

I assume that `post_id` is a number.  Compare numbers to numbers, not to strings.

EDIT:

If you want this *per* post_id, then just use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.score = (select min(t2.score) from t t2 where t2.post_id = t.post_id);
```

Comment: What if I have thousands of rows and want post_id to be unique for the lowest values?

Comment: @TomHarisond . . . Then you would have a different question.  You should be clear in the questions that you ask.  The purpose of this site is not "guess my question".  The purpose is to answer well-constructed questions.  The question you have here is clearly filtering by `post_id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you may have multiple rows with the lowest score, you can do it with a sub-query :

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE post_id = 1
AND score = (
  SELECT MIN(score)
  FROM test 
  WHERE post_id = 1
)
```

Fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ppntnA77HFpKRU82h32Gv/1

Answer (score 0):

The below should do the trick:

```sql
Select
    id, 
    score, 
    Post_id,
    min(score)
from 
    table
where 
    score = min(score);
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a valid query as it's missing GROUP BY clauses

Answer (score 0):

IF you're using MySQL v8.0, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to order the result. That way you can choose the row with the lower score and return everything from it:

```
select
    sq.id, sq.post_id, sq.score
from
    (select id, post_id, score
        , row_number() over (partition by post_id order by score) RowNo 
    from test) sq
where sq.RowNo = 1
```

Here is a Fiddle to test the code: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=8dHSCs50Iq

I also included another post_id beside your sample data, to demonstrate how it reacts to multiple post_id's

Comment: I am using Mysql 5.7.

Comment: Unfortunately v5.7 does NOT support `ROW_NUMBER()`. I would suggest Tajni 's solution, beacuse it's it the most transparent